# Is semi-simplicity of Galois representations local?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations, absolute-galois-group

Let $\rho:G_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \text{Gl}(V)$ be a finite dimensional $\ell$-adic Galois representation. Then for each prime, by pre-composing $\rho$ with the natural inclusion $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\rightarrow G_{\mathbb{Q}}$, we get a representation of the local Galois group. I'm curious about how the property of being semisimple behaves under localization, that is to say if $\rho$ is semisimple, can we conclude that $\rho\vert_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is semisimple?

Conversely, if for all $p\neq \ell$ (or maybe all primes) $\rho_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is semisimple, does it follow that $\rho$ is semisimple? If I'm not mistaken, all the  $\rho_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ being semisimple implies that $\rho\vert_{\bigcup_p G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is semistable, and since ${\bigcup_p G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is of finite index in $G_\mathbb{Q}$ (I think), this would mean $\rho$ is semisimple.

Comment: If $E/\mathbf{Q}$ is a non-CM elliptic curve and $\ell>3$ is a prime where $E$ has good ordinary reduction, then $V_\ell E$ is a semisimple $G_\mathbf{Q}$-representation but it is not semisimple as a $G_{\mathbf{Q}_\ell}$-representation.

Comment: If a newform $f$ is ordinary at $p$ then the local Galois representation at $p$ is upper-triangular (Deligne, Mazur-Wiles) but usually it does not split. See the papers of Eknath Ghate, e.g. *On the local behaviour of ordinary modular Galois representations*

Comment: @DavidHansen Out of curiosity, if $\ell$ is a prime of bad reduction, is it clear what to expect?